# No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString de mi proyecto

Tags: c#, stored-procedure

edito mi pregunta:
Tengo un problema con mi cadena de conexión, pero creo que mas propiamente es cuando intento abrir mi conexión.
porque les digo esto, porque consigo insertar registros, también consigo leer los registros desde mi base de datos, ahora mi problema se traslado a cuando llamo a mi formulario de agregarEstado desde mi formulario ListaEstados.
Cuando se produce el error:
Les comentaba que tengo un botón en el formulario ListaEstados, que me abre como ShowDialog(), mi formulario (frmAgregarEstado.ShowDialog();), mi proposito es agregar otro registro y que al cerrar el formulario, se me actualice el listado de mis estados. les repito cuando mi formulario esta en este punto frmAgregarEstado.ShowDialog(), se agrega el registro pero ya no se consigue actualizar la lista de estados.
tal vez mis imagenes no sean relevantes, pero me pidieron que les muetres y es lo que intentare hacer, para dar mas detalles de mi problema, tal vez no les parezca relevantes pero mostrare mis imagenes
[image: Imagenes de mis formularios]

Ahora bien el error que me muestra es el siguiente:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString.'
y me lo muestra justo en esta línea de código:

```
conexion.Open();
```

y cuando me muestra el error, cuando doy click en el botón cancelar del formulario y cuando agrego un registro e intento actualizar mi listado para que se muestre el registro agregado.
Hora les mostra el código que tengo para hecho comenzaré por la clase de conexión

```
public class BDConexion : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection conexion;
    private string connectionString;

    public BDConexion()
    {
        connectionString = "Data Source=Casa;Initial Catalog=POSmartDB;Integrated Security=True;";
        conexion = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    }

    public SqlConnection AbrirConexion()
    {
        if (conexion.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
                conexion.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error al abrir la conexión: " + ex.Message);
                throw; 
            }
        }
        return conexion;
    }

    public void CerrarConexion()
    {
        if (conexion.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            try
            {
                conexion.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error al cerrar la conexión: " + ex.Message);
                throw; 
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            CerrarConexion();
            conexion.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, el siguiente código es el método, que lista todos mis estados:

```
public DataTable ListarEstados()
    {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection connection = bdConexion.AbrirConexion())
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_ListarEstados", connection))

        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                return dataTable;

            }
        }

    }
```

El siguiente código es el que tiene mi botón para llamar a mi formulario de agregar un estado

```
private void btn_AddEstado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Frm_Filtro filtro = new Frm_Filtro();
        FrmAgregarEstado frmAgregarEstado = new FrmAgregarEstado();
        filtro.Show();
        frmAgregarEstado.ShowDialog();
        filtro.Hide();
        if (frmAgregarEstado.Tag.ToString() == "A")
        {
            CargarTodosLosEstados();
        }
    }
```

El siguiente código es el método para agregar un estado

```
private void InsertarEstado()
    {
        RN_Estados rN_Estados = new RN_Estados();
        EN_Estados eN_Estados = new EN_Estados();

        try
        {
            eN_Estados.Nombre = txtEstado.Text;
            rN_Estados.RN_InsertarEstado(eN_Estados);
                // Mostrar un mensaje de éxito.
                MostrarMensaje("Registro insertado correctamente");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El error es " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Este es el código del botón de mi formulario agregarRegistro

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Validar el formulario.
        if (!ValidarFormulario())
        {
            return;
        }

        // Insertar el estado en la base de datos.
        InsertarEstado();
        LimpiarControles();
        //this.Tag = "A";
        this.Tag = "A";
        this.Close();   
    }
```

Cuando agrego un punto de depuración en esta línea del código
[image: Punto de depuración]
me lleva a la capa de Negocios

```
 public DataTable RN_ListarEstados()
    {
        return bdEstados.ListarEstados();
    }
```

y esta me lleva nuevamente al método de la capa de datos
[image: Punto de depuración de mi capa de datos]

el mismo que me lleva a la clase BdConexion
al método:

```
public SqlConnection AbrirConexion()
    {
        if (conexion.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
                conexion.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error al abrir la conexión: " + ex.Message);
                throw; 
            }
        }
        return conexion;
    }
```

y es en ese momento que se produce el error siguiente
[image: Mensaje de error]
Este es el código de mi botón Cancelar

```
private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tag = "";
        this.Close();
    }
```

Les aclaro que cuando llamo al formulario de agregar estado de la forma normal, no en modo showDialog(), y presiono el botón cancelar no se produce el error, pero cuando lo llamo desde mi otro formulario si se produce el error.

Esperando haber dato toda la información que a mi criterio es relevante, por favor les pido que me ayuden a esclarecer cual es el error, y a darle solución

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar

Comment: Te falta el connection string, el error no puede ser más claro

Comment: Entonces suponiendo que el connection string esté en algún lado que no veo, tu problema puede en los `using` del 3er código. Para descartar que sea esto, elimínalos y prueba si persiste el error. Luego me avisas para que busquemos una solución permanente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

está bien lo que dice  Yussef, al hacer esto:

using (SqlConnection connection = bdConexion.AbrirConexion())

estás desechando la conección sql de la instacia bdConexion, por lo que la conección queda vacía, si aún la puedes ver viva es solo porque el depurador te permite eso, pero si ves las propiedades verás que no tiene nada.

Entonces puedes hacer tu SqlConenction pública así:

```
 public SqlConnection conexion;
```

Y hacerlo luego así por ejemplo:

```
   using (BDConexion bdConexion = new BDConexion())
   {
       bdConexion.AbrirConexion();

       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_ListarEstados",bdConexion.conexion))
       {
           command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

           using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
           {
               adapter.Fill(dataTable);

           }
       }
   }
```

o mejor así:

```
  BDConexion bdConexion = new BDConexion();
  bdConexion.AbrirConexion();

  // hacer todo lo que quieras

  bdConexion.Dispose();
```

Comment: Muy buen aporte gracias